# Regex to Exclude only certain characters

Tags: java, regex

I have set of url like this,

```
www.abc.com/some-text/
www.xyz.com/some-text/
www.pqr.com/page/2/
```

I need get URl expect the url containing the word "page"
My regex is `.*/(.(?!page)).*`
IT is not working.can anyone point me the problem and solution for this?

Comment: And what if `page` appears somewhere else than in the path? For instance, `foo.bar/baz?page=4`?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you looking for regex? This can be done using `String.contains(String s)`

```
String string ="www.pqr.com/page/2/";
if(string.contains("page")){
    //true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following regular expression. (Specify `^`, `$` to make sure no character is followed by `page`).

```
"^(.(?!\\bpage\\b))+$"
```

---

```
String pattern = "^(.(?!\\bpage\\b))+$";
System.out.println("www.abc.com/some-text/".matches(pattern)); // true
System.out.println("www.xyz.com/some-text/".matches(pattern)); // true
System.out.println("www.pqr.com/page/2/".matches(pattern));    // false
```

Comment: No need to specify the `^` and `$` anchors with `String#matches`, it's already matching on the whole input string. It doesn't make the regex wrong though, just a little bit redundant :)

Comment: @sp00m, You're right. Thank you for comment. I'll leave the answer as-is for other usecase that does not involve `String.matches`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean except or expect on your question??

You can ignore urls having `page` in it by `lookahead` option.

```
/^(?!.*page).*/
```

If you want to pick urls having page in it, then

```
/^(?=.*page).*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `URI`:

```
public boolean containsPage(final String input)
{
    return URI.create(input).getPath().contains("page");
}
```

This allows to search for `page` *only* in the path component and will not be fooled if present in the host name/query string/fragment part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX :

```
(^(?:.(?!\bpage\b))+$)
```

Check **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG5pL5)**

CODE :

```
String regex="(^(?:.(?!\\bpage\\b))+$)";
String lines[]={
        "www.abc.com/some-text/",
        "www.xyz.com/some-text/",
        "www.pqr.com/page/2/"   
};
for(String line:lines){
    if(line.matches(regex)){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
www.abc.com/some-text/
www.xyz.com/some-text/
```

**EXPLANATION**

[image]